# Javascript SweetAlert not working?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

This html document

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
    SweetAlert('a', 'b', 'c');
</script>
```

is not working. I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: SweetAlert is not defined`

If i use `swal()` instead of `SweetAlert()` i get

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null`

The same test with sweetalert2

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.5/sweetalert2.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.5/sweetalert2.common.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.5/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

i get the following

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at sweetalert2.common.min.js:1

sweetalert2.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
    at u (sweetalert2.min.js:1)
    at c (sweetalert2.min.js:1)
    at U (sweetalert2.min.js:1)
    at e (sweetalert2.min.js:1)
    at test:8
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Error A

You were calling `SweetAlert(...)` instead of `sweetAlert(...)`. First letter should be in lower case.

## Error B

If you are using the third argument, it should be `warning`, `error`, `success` or `info`

```js
sweetAlert("title", "description", "error");
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is also working for 

`swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "Your will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  closeOnConfirm: false
},
function(){
  swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
});`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a name like sweetAlert. You can use `swal('Title', 'Message', 'type')` instead of sweetAlert

```js
swal("HEY", "Message", "warning")
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

//Define.

```
    <script src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sweetalert.css">
```

//For Call

```
    function callSweetMsg(){
        swal({
        title: "Error!",``
        text: "Here's my error message!",
        type: "error",
        confirmButtonText: "Cool"
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Type must be in small case like warning, error, success or info.